# Save image from another model/controller via url and not form post

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

Another team member has written the feature to allow users to upload a photo using a http form and the Rails Paperclip gem.

I am currently working on a feature to import a list of photos from the users Facebook album.

I currently have a list of the Facebook image URLs that need to be saved. I am able to get rails to download them and save to a location but I can't figure out how to trigger the paperclip process.

Where is the best place to add in my code to download the image from the URL?

Any ideas appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the following question that answers my question.

[Paperclip fetch image directly via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830122/paperclip-fetch-image-directly-via-url)

Here's what i'm doing to save my image:

```
      photo = Photo.new
      photo.picture_from_url("http://image_url_here..")
      photo.name = "photo_name"
      photo.description = "photo_description"
      photo.user_id = current_user.id
      photo.album_id = album_id
      photo.save
```

And I have this function in the Photo model. Note, *picture* is the image field that paperclip uses.

```
def picture_from_url(url)
    self.picture = open(url)
end
```