# How to save an image in paperclip via URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, url, paperclip

In rails 3.2.13, i am trying to save some bulk data by uploading an csv file. While saving it i need to save some images also related to this data. I need to save this image by fetching from URL. How to save this kind of image using `paperclip`? How to provide an image data in csv file?

Eg: I have one User model & it has one profile_picture association, first i need to save the image to assets table & associate it to user model.

I have tried [Paperclip fetch image directly via url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4830122/paperclip-fetch-image-directly-via-url)
 & also i have installed **gem install rest-open-uri** but it is showing some error.

Errors are, first i got installation error for rest-open-uri after installing it again i got `AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'create' could not be found for UsersController)`

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I had the same problem. And i finally switched to Carrierwave. But Daniël Zwijnenburg answer should work.

Comment: I have paperclip and it works great with remote urls. What is this "some error"?

Comment: some error means, first i got installation error for rest-open-uri after installing it again i got AbstractController::ActionNotFound (The action 'create' could not be found for UsersController)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I did it on my apps :
Let's say I want to save an avatar for my user ( I added paperclip to the user model )

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
user.avatar = URI.parse("http://www.xxxx.xxx/image.jpg")
user.save
```

That should work for you,